# WordPress - getElementsByClassName|0|.innerHTML is always null

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add some text dynamically based on user choice for a variable WooCommerce product : If the user select the annual classic subscription, a summary displays "Your choice : annual classic subscription, 60€ per year".
So, I want to get the variation ID from the add-to-cart button and then the script add the corresponding string in summary.
First, I've tried this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("variation_id")[0].value;
```

and to test it, this :

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("variation_id");
console.log(x[0].value);
```

but the console returns

> "undefined is not an object"...

So I've tried to do the same with a paragraph element with a class and `.innerHTML` instead of .value just to check. It doesn't work too.
I've tried on other element and also with `getElementById` and the console still returns

> "undefined is not an object"

or

> "null is not an object".

Any ideas ?
This is the link : https://pour.press/produit/abonnement-numerique/

Comment: Please share the HTML of the element you're trying to select. Also, please let us know *where* on your page your JavaScript is, and whether or not it's wrapped in an `onload` or similar handler. When I go to the page you've linked and run your code in console, it prints `1692`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Because of WordPress, the HTML full code is too long and the simplest way to see what element I'm trying to select is to inspect the button "Je m'abonne". The JS is in a plugin, I've just reactivated it (you can see it in console now) and this is the result : 
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x[0].value')

Comment: There is no element with className of `variation_id` so `x` is empty, so `x[0]` gives you undefined.

Comment: The error shows when I press the button and page is redirected to https://pour.press/finalisation/ where there is no such element. It is present on the page you linked above but there error doesn’t occur.